# Telephone book algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This is an exam practice question i've been working on, i know of methods to do this but as the question states i don't know which would be the most efficient.

You
are
given
a
telephone
book
listing
the
surnames
of
people
in
alphabetical
order.

Describe
the
fastest
method
(clearly
explain
what
you
have
to
do)
you
can
use
to
find
a
given
surname.

If
there
are
n
people
listed
in
the
telephone
book,
what
is
the
Big
O
complexity
of
your
fastest
method
(and
explain
why)?

Comment: So, no thoughts on that?

Comment: Hi, you seem new where. We're happy to help you with questions - but it will be better for you if you have a go at it first and just ask us to help yu with the bits where you get stuck. So why don't you tell us what you've done so far to solve this... have you googled?  Are there any parts of the question that you can have a guess at the answer? If so - please edit your question and include that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you know the phone book entries are in order already. This means that a binary search is probably your best bet. This search works by cutting the number of entries to search in half on each iteration. It only works if your data is already sorted however. Check out this website for time complexity in Big O notation: http://bigocheatsheet.com

Edit wording